# Token renewal in Autodesk Forge Viewer

Tags: javascript, autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

When rendering the Viewer, a token is required to access the model data with its URN.

What I am currently doing is:

- Each time the HTML page is loaded: call the authentication endpoint to get a token
- Provide this token to the viewer

To do this, I put the `client_id` and `client_secret` inside the JS like this (code based on [Step 1: Prepare your HTML](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v2/tutorials/basic-viewer/#step-1-prepare-your-html)):

```js
fetch('https://developer.api.autodesk.com/authentication/v1/authenticate',
{
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    },
    body: new URLSearchParams({
        'client_id': '*****',
        'client_secret': '*****',
        'grant_type': 'client_credentials',
        'scope': 'viewables:read'
    })
})
.then(res => res.json())
.then(value => {
    var viewer;
    var options = {
        env: 'AutodeskProduction',
        accessToken: value.access_token
    };
    var documentId = 'urn:*****';
    Autodesk.Viewing.Initializer(options, function onInitialized(){
        Autodesk.Viewing.Document.load(documentId, onDocumentLoadSuccess, onDocumentLoadFailure);
    });
});
```

Which is obviously a terrible thing because secrets are exposed in client side.

In [Step 2: Token expiration](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v2/tutorials/basic-viewer/#step-2-token-expiration), it is stated that

> developers can (and should) provide a function that can fetch a new access token [from the backend]

```js
var options = {
    env: 'AutodeskProduction',
    getAccessToken: function(onGetAccessToken) {
        //
        // TODO: Replace static access token string below with call to fetch new token from your backend
        // Both values are provided by Forge's Authentication (OAuth) API.
        //
        // Example Forge's Authentication (OAuth) API return value:
        // {
        //    "access_token": "<YOUR_APPLICATION_TOKEN>",
        //    "token_type": "Bearer",
        //    "expires_in": 86400
        // }
        //
        var accessToken = '<YOUR_APPLICATION_TOKEN>';
        var expireTimeSeconds = 86400;
        onGetAccessToken(accessToken, expireTimeSeconds);
    }
}
```

I don't understand which backend we are talking about here as we only have static HTML/JS. Can you please provide an example of such token renewal function and where should it reside?

Is there somewhere a runtime renewing the token, even if nobody accesses the HTML page for a long time?

Thanks guys.

Answer (score 2):

About the token expiration, I think the getAccessToken function renews automatically the token so you just need to provide a function to fetch a new token as described in the comment.

For the backend, there is probably some ways to only use html/js and hide your credentials but it's not the recommended way.

All the Forge dev I have made and seen from the Forge Team were made with a backend (NodeJS, C#, PHP ... you can choose your favorite language)

You can follow this tutorial showing this with NodeJS :

[Forge Getting Started](https://forge.autodesk.com/developer/learn/viewer-app/overview)

You can also check the [Autodesk-Forge Github](https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge) where you can find a lot of different examples.

Answer (score 0):

When building a Forge application you typically have to implement a basic backend, at least for generating the access token (as opposed to - as you correctly pointed out - requesting the token directly from the client and exposing the client ID and secret).

To create a simple server using .NET Core, Node.js, Java, PHP, or Go, go to the https://learnforge.autodesk.io/#/environment/setup/2legged tutorial and select the language of your choice.